# UIScrollView deletion is not working properly

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which has paging enabled etc... I add a delete button ontop of a UIImageView which is added to the UIScrollView. However when I add three images from the library to the scrollView and then delete all of them by pressing the delete button, it works properly. But when I do the same process again, it leaves UIImageViews on the UIScrollView still even though the pageControl's numberofpages is 0.

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
- (void) updateScrollView {
    CGRect currentFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    currentFrame.origin.x = 0;
    numberOfPages = [[self selectedImages] count];
    if ([self.selectedImages count] > 0) {
    for (UIImage *image in [self selectedImages]) {
            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
            [btn setTag:[[self selectedImages] indexOfObject:image]];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeImageView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            UIImageView *imagev = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            [imagev setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
            [imagev setFrame:currentFrame];
            [imagev addSubview:btn];
            [imagev setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:imagev];
            [imagev release];
            currentFrame.origin.x = currentFrame.origin.x + currentFrame.size.width;
        }
    }
    else {
        [self.selectedImages removeAllObjects];
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
            [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
        }
        return;
    }
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [self.selectedImages count];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(currentFrame.origin.x, currentFrame.size.height)];
}
- (void) removeImageView:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self.selectedImages count] >= 1) {
        int i = sender.tag;
        id superv = [sender superview];
        [superv removeFromSuperview];
        [self.selectedImages removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        [self updateScrollView];
    }
    else {
        [self.selectedImages removeAllObjects];
    }
    return;
}
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    currentPage = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentPage];
    return;
}
- (void) updatePageControl:(id)sender {
    UIPageControl *pg = (UIPageControl *)sender;
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pg.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
- (void) removeObject:(id)object {
    [self.selectedImages removeObject:object];
    [self updateScrollView];
    [self updatePageControl:self.pageControl];
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    currentPage = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentPage];

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you remove the first image view, you're calling updateScrollView and you have 2 images left. In updateScrollView, first if condition will evaluate to YES and you'll be adding another two images to scroll view, so now, there are 2 pairs of images. when Next one is deleted, you delete two images and add 4 more.

Also, Please be aware that UIScrollView keeps scrollbars in its subviews array so this is no good.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [self.scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
            [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

You should polish this code before moving on. Put breakpoint on each method or just NSLog(@"%s", __ FUNCTION __); (remove spaces between underscores and FUNCTION!) at the beginning of each method and get to know what is called when and by whom. When you begin to understand how code works, solutions to your original question will appear out of nowhere. Unfortunately, I cannot help you as you forgot to mention how you're doing "the same process again".